# getting highest date in multidimensional array with id

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Where the sub arrays have similar `id`s, I want to select only those with the highest date.

```
$array = [
           ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1994'],
           ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1996'],
           ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1997'],
           ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1998'],
           ['id' => 9, 'date' => '10-24-1998'],
           ['id' => 9, 'date' => '10-24-2001'],
           ['id' => 9, 'date' => '10-24-1997'],
           ['id' => 8, 'date' => '10-24-1996'],
           ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1999'],
           ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1991'],
           ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1993'],
           ['id' => 8, 'date' => '10-24-2001']
         ]; /* array i have */

$expected_Result = [
                     ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1999'],
                     ['id' => 9, 'date'=> '10-24-2001'],
                     ['id' => 8, 'date' => '10-24-2001'],
                   ];
 /* array which i expected */
```

Comment: _i have tried so many..._ Post the best approach you have been trying

Comment: Is it is result of database query, you can change it as appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use this as the solution, in order to have an array where the key is the id itself:

```
/** 
 * @param array{id:int, date:string} $list
 *
 * @return array<int,string> 
 */
function sortDatesUniqueById(array $list): array
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($list as ['id' => $id, 'date' => $date]) {
        if (!isset($result[$id]) || $result[$id] < $date) {
            $result[$id] = $date;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Or another approach, to get exactly what you are asking for:

```
/** 
 * @param array{id:int, date:string} $list
 *
 * @return array{id:int, date:string} 
 */
function sortDatesUniqueById(array $list): array
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($list as ['id' => $id, 'date' => $date]) {
        if (!isset($result[$id]) || $result[$id]['date'] < $date) {
            $result[$id] = ['id' => $id, 'date' => $date];
        }
    }

    return array_values($result);
}
```

PHPDoc used based on the standard https://github.com/phan/phan (generic arrays and array shapes).

Comment: I like the `foreach ($list as ['id' => $id, 'date' => $date])` - nice!

Comment: Yeah, it's a feature named "array destructuring" (up from PHP 7.1). I like it pretty much :)

Comment: You can see that feature and all the most interesting features from PHP 7 here: https://medium.com/@chemaclass/e3b2bf5916b2

Answer (score 2):

Just loop over the array, check if that ID exists as an index in the `$result` array. If it does, check if the new date is bigger than the current one - if yes, overwrite it with the new value.

```php
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    if (!isset($result[$v['id']])) {
        $result[$v['id']] = $v['date'];
    } elseif ($result[$v['id']] < $v['date']) {
        $result[$v['id']] = $v['date'];
    }
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/7jadP

Comment: perhaps, you need array_values after

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.

```php
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (!in_array($value['id'], array_column($result, 'id'))) {
        $result[] = $value;
    } else {
        foreach ($result as $key => $res) {
            if ($res['id'] === $value['id'] && $value['date'] < $res['date']) {
                $result[$key]['date'] = $value['date'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First iterate over each value, if it is not in the list, add to the `$result` var, else, iterate over the `$result` value and check when the id is the same whith the current `$value` and finally check wich date is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can user `array_multisort()` and finally `array_walk()` to make the array unique.

```
array_multisort(
    array_column($array, 'id'), SORT_DESC, 
    array_column($array, 'date'), SORT_DESC, 
    $array
);

$result = [];
array_walk($array, function ($item) use (&$result) {
    !isset($result[$item['id']]) && $result[$item['id']] = $item['date'];
});

print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one liner,
First sort by id desc and date asc. Then make key as id so that last date of it will override every small dates. Then to reset index use [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'id'), SORT_DESC, array_column($array, 'date'), SORT_ASC, $array);
$result = array_values(array_column($array, null, "id"));
print_r($result);
```

[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array

> **Note:** **column_key:** The column of values to return. This value may be an integer key
>   of the column you wish to retrieve, or it may be a string key name for
>   an associative array or property name. It may also be **NULL** to
>   return complete arrays or objects (this is useful together with
>   index_key to reindex the array).

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/NVm75)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [date] => 10-24-1999
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [date] => 10-24-2001
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [date] => 10-24-2001
        )

)
```

Comment: That's two lines ;)

Comment: It should not be about the lines but how easy is to understand for other developers.

Comment: Aye! Optimization skills come with knowledge and ease of development things in likelihood of better ways.

Answer (score 0):

We can sort the array first by id and date ascending, and then use array_column to pull out the highest dates.

```
$array = [
    ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1994'],
    ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1996'],
    ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1997'],
    ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1998'],
    ['id' => 9, 'date' => '10-24-1998'],
    ['id' => 9, 'date' => '10-24-2001'],
    ['id' => 9, 'date' => '10-24-1997'],
    ['id' => 8, 'date' => '10-24-1996'],
    ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1999'],
    ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1991'],
    ['id' => 10, 'date' => '10-24-1993'],
    ['id' => 8, 'date' => '10-24-2001']
]; 

uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $r = $a['id'] <=> $b['id'];
    if($r == 0)
        return $a['date']<=>$b['date'];
    return $r;
});

var_export(array_column($array, null, 'id'));
```

Output:

```
array (
  8 => 
  array (
    'id' => 8,
    'date' => '10-24-2001',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'id' => 9,
    'date' => '10-24-2001',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'id' => 10,
    'date' => '10-24-1999',
  ),
)
```